# Null pointer exception error using a 2d object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, 2d

I am having a problem. I have a class called Space.
private spaceColour colour;

```
public class Space {

public enum spaceColour{
    Black, White, Null;
}

private spaceColour colour;

public Space (spaceColour colour)
{
    this.setColour(colour);
}

public spaceColour getColour() {
    return colour;
}

public void setColour(spaceColour colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}
```

}

Using Space, I create a 2d array of this object, in this method

```
public void testMethods()
  {
   Space[][] test = new Space[2][2];
LINE:252   test[0][0].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
   test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
   test[1][0].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
   test[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black);

   ThreeinaRow(test);

   for(int row= 0; row<test.length;row++)
   {
       for(int column = 0; column<test.length;column++)
       {
           if (test[row][column].getColour().equals(spaceColour.White))
           {
               System.out.println("Whites at row:" + row + "Column: "+ column);
           }
       }
   }
 }
```

The three in a row method basically adds on spaces with a particular colour.

I'm getting a Null pointer exception at line 252 as indicated. I really don't understand why, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've instantiated the array, but not the objects.

```
test[0][0] = new Space();
test[0][0].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
test[0][1] = new Space();
test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
test[1][0] = new Space();
test[1][0].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
test[1][1] = new Space();
test[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
```

Comment: +1 Also `test[0][0] = new Space(spaceColour.Black);` would work as there is a constructor with that signature in his class.

Comment: Is there any way to intitialise say a 4x4 Space array, where all of the Spaces are already initialised to spaceColour.Null?

Comment: Try this: Arrays.fill(test, new Space()); put it after the line where you declare it, but before you then access the array

Comment: Do you mean Arrays.fill(test,new Space(spaceColour.Null)); ?

Comment: bloody constructor! :p